# Mejorar respuesta Select No avanza - Oracle 12c - Linux

Tags: oracle-12c

necesito mejorar esta sentencia:

```
select  /*+ parallel(ASSET_MP,16)*/  distinct FF.ID_MAYORISTA, 
    FF.NUMERO_PROFORMA, 
    FF.PERIODO, 
    FF.FECHA_RECARGA, 
    FF.ID_RECARGA, 
    FF.NRO_LINEA, 
    FF.MONTO_RECARGA, 
    FF.CONSUMO_DATOS, 
    FF.CONSUMO_VOZ, 
    FF.NOMBRE_ARCHIVO, 
     A.MSISDN__C ,
     A.VLOCITY_CMT__BILLINGACCOUNTID_, 
     B.ID, B.BILLINGSTATECODE, 
     B.CUSTOMERINTEGRATIONID__C, 
     B.ACCOUNTINTEGRATIONID__C, 
     B.BILLING_ADDRESS__C, 
     C.ID, 
     C.LOCATION_ID__C, 
     C.PROVINCE__C, 
     D.ID, 
     D.MUNICIPALITY__C, 
     D.STATENAME__C
     from A001540.FF_ENTIDAD_MERCADOPAGO_AUX FF 
     left join A001540.ASSET_MP A on FF.nro_linea = A.MSISDN__C 
     left join A001540.ACCOUNT B on A.VLOCITY_CMT__BILLINGACCOUNTID_ = B.id 
     left join A001540.ADDRESS2__C C on B.BILLING_ADDRESS__C = C.id 
     left join A001540.LOCATION__C D on C.LOCATION_ID__C = D.id
     where FF.ASSET_BILLINGACC is null;
```

Adjunto: Rows_Count_Explain_Plan_and_Indexes.txt

La ejecucion del select, nunca me devuelve resultados

Podrian darme tips para intentar una mejora?

Gracias

---

--PLAN de ejecucion en imagen --
[image: Plan de ejecucion]

Comment: No adjuntaste nada... no se pueden adjuntar archivos...

Comment: no me deja añadir mas codigo...

Comment: tenes un table access full a la tabla account...